# Can't copy a valid file in python

Tags: python, windows, file, copy

**UPDATE: IMPORTANT**
Ok, so I've been worried about the length of the file name for some time now, as I know windows, sometimes, has an issue with file names larger than 256 characters. These ones seem to be over that hitting 260 characters. So it's not the code rather a limitation.

---

I've create a python script that among other thing is meant to copy, a number of files which have been skipped.  Now I've run into a snag where **SOME** files are not being copied.  Now these files are on our share and tend to have really long names. I am almost certain this plays a part as they are 260 characters in length. Does anyone have a way around this?

**Code:** **EDIT** -- I've edited the code to try @realizedvariance suggestion

```
if not file_path=="":
    if not file_path.find("~$") > 0:
        folder_name, file_name = os.path.split(file_path)
        if os.path.exists(folder_name):
            for thefile in os.listdir(folder_name): 
                if thefile.lower().rstrip().lstrip() == file_name.lower().rstrip().lstrip():
                    print thefile
                    print os.path.exists(folder_name)
                    print os.path.exists(os.path.join(folder_name, thefile))
```

The files in which they are failing are files with the name like:

Here is the response of the print:

```
Draft DR 129123 CP, Amendment No. 3 to AS NaZT 60335.2.11 2009 Household and similar electrical appliances - Safety – Part 2.11  .msg
True
False
DaltaPlaneR Business Information Newsletter - Issue 79, 2010 - Social Networking Apps in Business - Grail Roads Ltd.msg
True
False
From DaltaPlaneR - Business Newsletter - Issue 78 - 2009 - Important Terms of Trade - Strategic Businesses Ltd.msg
True
False
```

So it prints File Name, If the folder location is true, and then if the full location is true. Bear in mind it literally got the file names from `os.listdir(path)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the filenames in both lists are exactly the same case and formatting? Perhaps try a simple change:

```
for thefile.lower().rstrip().lstrip() == file_name.lower().rstrip().lstrip()
```

Not the most elegant, but that might be something to check. There could also be a unicode / string issue. Try wrapping them in str() as well.

Comment: I can't be 100% certain however when i copy/paste the output's in notepad and compare them they seem to have the exact same output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the ability to comment or I would.

The output of the script would help a lot. I thought it may be because of the spaces but I've manually tested your script specifying both `file_path = '/home/user/test.txt'` and `file_path = '/home/user/test 2.txt'` without fail. How are you setting the variable? Are you setting it with some syntax that is interpreting spaces as the end of the filename? If so try escaping the spaces like so `'\ '`.

Comment: I'm not quiet certain what you mean by the output of the script? Do you mean the traceback? If so it's just the `IOError file path does not exist`.  as mentioned I get the variable from an error log, which is parsed and stored. I will try use a `.replace()` statement and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was correct about the file path name being too long.  What I needed was a UNC command to exclude the **MAX_PATH** from the request I was making.

What I needed to include `\\?\UNC` as the prefix to my file_path string which ultimately translates to `\\\\?\UNC`

Here's the code below:

```
if not file_path=="":
        if not file_path.find("~$") > 0:
            file_path="\\\\?\UNC"+file_path
            print os.path.exists(file_path)
```

The information I found was from a Microsoft MSDN topic on MAX_PATH from the post of [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath)
It's important to understand that I am also using a server based share so I needed the file path "\\" intact.